# New Windows 10 Accounts Badly Broken

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have been looking at this issue for a while.

I am running Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit Version 1703 OS Build 15063.540

I have tried to create a new user tonight, I tried to add my son through microsoft family and the account would simply not login, I switched him to an administrators account and I got in but the account is badly damaged, no startmenu, no background no nothing.

I removed him from my family and decided to create an account manually using

```
net user /add testuser1 <password>
net localgroup Administrators testuser1 /add
```

both commands executed successfully.

When I log in I am greeted with a totally black background, the taskbar is there but the start menus isn't there and I can't launch anything at all not even cmd.exe from the run box.

I'm not sure why this has happened I have 3 accounts on the machine that work perfectly and my log is not full of errors. I am wondering if the accounts are based on some sort of template that may be corrupt but I am a little beyond my ops knowledge.

This is a dev box albeit a home one and would incur significant effort to reinstall so before I do that does anyone know how to fix this? I can't create new accounts that I can use to log in on. At least interactively.

Also worth a mention is if I create the user as a normal user and not an administrator it simply doesn't leave the login screen but immediately logs them out.

Interestingly all other accounts were created before creators update, Hmm I wonder.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to delete your son's profile and simply create a new user?

Comment: All new users are broken, that's the point so thats what I did and all users I create are very badly broken indicating they suffer from the same issue. I've done all the obvious stuff like sfc, and checking my updates with dism etc.

Comment: *"I am wondering if the accounts are based on some sort of template that may be corrupt but I am a little beyond my ops knowledge."*  Just to double-check, nobody deleted or modified the `C:\Users\Default` folder on that machine, did they?

Comment: There are two things there called default they are 'Default' a directory and a junction called Default User which points to c:\users\default, both are hidden

Comment: I hate to recycle what everyone eventually says to do with Win10, but try running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth && sfc /scannow`, then reboot. Once that's completed, create a local account for him. If all goes well, you can link his microsoft account later. (Nice question syntax, btw. Love proper english :D)

Comment: done it made no difference Dooley_labs

Comment: Understood... that's why I specifically emphasized the exact folder path.  That folder is essentially the template that you mentioned, and it is utilized as a baseline to create a new user profile folder whenever another account is added to the machine.

Comment: Is there any way of telling if it's been corrupted? And if so fixing it, I'm hoping that's what this is as the machine is otherwise healthy. If my logs were filling up I'd be flattening the machine without bothering here.

Comment: Ok so I've gone to my backups and pulled the images out of cold store and they are the same, so I went to my business laptop and copied its default profile and aside times etc they to are almost identical so we can rule out that folder, maybe.

Comment: What happens if you add an account via _Settings > Accounts > Family & Other People > Other People > Add someone else to this PC_?  I know nothing about what happens on the backend for family accts, but from the descr, it appears main user <parent> retains a level of control over family accts. If this is the case, there could be corruption in the main user's <parent> userprofile. To rule out, create a new local account (non-family), make it an admin; downgrade your current account to a non-admin, add family member from new local account. Otherwise a _repair install_ may be required

Comment: fixed it, default user profile was screwed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going into backups and restoring my default user profile, whilst running a new backup after restore I have since found my spanky new ssd is throwing CRC errors, trying to get that replaced on warranty.